# CGAL: adding features fails

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, mesh, cgal

## The task

is simple: I want to create a tetrahedral mesh and I want to add several features to it.

## Example

As an input, take the file `cube.off` that can be found in `CGAL-4.11/examples/Mesh_3/data`. The features I would like to add (just the twelve edges of the cube) are saved in `cube.edges`:

```
2 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1
2 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 -1
2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1
2 -1 1 -1 1 1 -1
2 -1 1 -1 -1 1 1
2 1 1 -1 1 -1 -1
2 1 1 -1 1 1 1
2 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1
2 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1
2 -1 -1 1 1 -1 1
2 -1 1 1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1 1 -1 1
```

MWE of the code:

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_criteria_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedral_complex_mesh_domain_3.h>
#include <CGAL/make_mesh_3.h>

// From CGAL-4.11/examples/Mesh_3 but for simplicity copied to the current folder.
#include "read_polylines.h"

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_polyhedron_3<K>::type Polyhedron;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedral_complex_mesh_domain_3<K> Mesh_domain;
typedef CGAL::Sequential_tag Concurrency_tag;

typedef CGAL::Mesh_triangulation_3<Mesh_domain,CGAL::Default,Concurrency_tag>::type Tr;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<
  Tr,Mesh_domain::Corner_index,Mesh_domain::Curve_segment_index> C3t3;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_criteria_3<Tr> Mesh_criteria;

typedef K::Point_3 Point;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<Point> > Polylines;

int main()
{
  // Read the (one) patch.
  std::vector<Polyhedron> patches(1);
  std::ifstream input("cube.off");
  input >> patches[0];
  const std::pair<int, int> incident_subdomains[] = { std::make_pair(1,0) };
  Mesh_domain domain(patches.begin(), patches.end(), incident_subdomains, incident_subdomains+1);

  // Read the features.
  std::string feature_edges="cube.edges";
  Polylines polylines;
  read_polylines<Point>(feature_edges.c_str(), polylines);
  domain.add_features(polylines.begin(), polylines.end());

  // Create the mesh.
  Mesh_criteria criteria(CGAL::parameters::edge_size = 0.25);
  C3t3 c3t3 = CGAL::make_mesh_3<C3t3>(domain, criteria);

  // Write it (if it hasn't crashed before).
  std::ofstream medit_file("out.mesh");
  c3t3.output_to_medit(medit_file, false, true);
}
```

This (when compiled with the option `-DCGAL_MESH_3_VERBOSE`) crashes with the following error message:

```
Start volume scan...Scanning triangulation for bad cells (sequential)... terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CGAL::Assertion_exception'
  what():  CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!
Expr: patch_id > 0 && std::size_t(patch_id) < patch_id_to_polyhedron_id.size()
File: /yatmp/scr1/ya10813/cgal-install/include/CGAL/Polyhedral_complex_mesh_domain_3.h
Line: 457
Aborted
```

## Question

What am I missing? It must be something really basic. CGAL is a very reliable library that works well on complex data; I don't believe that a cube with 12 edges is enough to stop it.

## Things that I also tried

- When I replace the line `domain.add_features(polylines.begin(), polylines.end());` with `domain.detect_features();`, the program terminates correctly. The confusing part is that the detected features are *exactly* those that I am trying to add (I know that because I have made a function in `Mesh_domain_with_polyline_features_3` that printed the edges for me; I can share it here if necessary).
- When I use `Polyhedral_mesh_domain_with_features_3` instead of `Polyhedral_complex_mesh_domain_3`, the program terminates correctly. The features seem to be preserved in the resulting geometry. However, it is just one patch (all of the triangles in `out.mesh` have the same last number, whereas I want them to have numbers 0 to 11 in this case). **Edit:** To achieve that, one would have to either use `detect_features();` instead of `add_features(...);` or split the domain into patches and let CGAL create the complex from them. Thanks to @lrineau for the clarification.
- I also tried splitting the domain into several patches first. However, then the boundaries of the patches change. **Edit:** One way to keep them is to add the patch boundaries as features.
- Reversing the orientation of the surface (and swapping `0` and `1` in `incident_subdomains`): no visible change.
- Changing the order of the feature lines in `cube.edges`: no visible change.
- Linking with older version of Boost: no visible change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class [`Polyhedral_complex_mesh_domain_3`](https://doc.cgal.org/4.13/Mesh_3/classCGAL_1_1Polyhedral__complex__mesh__domain__3.html) is a new class added one year ago [in CGAL-4.11](https://www.cgal.org/2017/09/21/cgal411/#d-mesh-generation). The problem you got is that it was never tested without calling `domain.detect_features()`, and the code has a bug: the data member `patch_id_to_polyhedron_id` is only filled in `detect_features()`. That explains why it works when you call `detect_features()` instead of `add_features(..)`.

**Edit**: I have fixed that bug today, see the [PR #3393 of CGAL](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/3393). The fix will be in the future bug-fix releases CGAL-4.12.2 and CGAL-4.13.1.

Comment: Excellent, I am really relieved to hear this.

Comment: I have a fix. I have modified my answer. In my opinion, you can accept it, now.

Comment: Dear @lrineau, thank you a lot for the prompt bugfix. I recompiled and my program now terminates correctly. However, there is still a thing I am confused about: when I add the features like in the MWE, all triangles in `out.mesh` have the tag `2`. When I replace `add_features(...);` with `detect_features();`, the mesh looks the same but the triangles have tags `2` to `7` (consequently, medit shows it with 6 colours instead of one after pressing "e"). This is despite the fact that the detected features are the same as those that I manually add. Which behavior is correct?

Comment: `detect_features` detects sharp curves, but it also detect surface patches, and gives numbers to them.

Comment: I see, I wrongly assumed that `add_features` does the same. Everything works now, thank you very much for your time. I was really getting desperate recently. (=

Comment: I have also slightly edited the question to clarify the patches. Hopefully it will be clearer to people who may stumble over it in future.

Comment: Dear @lrineau, is there any plan as to when will CGAL-4.13.1 be available? My computer is happy to work with the bugfix downloaded from github but porting my solution to other people's computers would be easier if I could refer to an official release.

Comment: @anotherlispninjaonabike I usually publish the bug-fix release (like 4.13.1) just before the next beta release (4.14-beta1). That should be within the next month.